# Javascript Re-append a Removed element

Tags: javascript, html, append, element

On the HTML page I initially had a button.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="assembleTest()">
```

I removed it in a click function with this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("submit");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

I can't seem to access this button element again to re-append it. What is the best method to appending this again? Do I just need to re-create the button in Javascript again?

Comment: Why remove the input when you could simply disable it and then re-enable it when needed. <input type='submit' disabled='disabled'>

Comment: good to know I can do that, but it's not the effect I'm going for

Comment: Ok, how about wrapping the input in a div and hiding the div. The only other alternative, as suggested by Joseph, is to rebuild the button in dom and append it.

Comment: That is also a good idea, however I want to know how to properly append it again using the DOM. Here is a JSFiddle to an example of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/Natronox/xskxvjhe/#&togetherjs=soRqnMd5hS

Comment: I have settled with turning display to none... I suppose removing things directly from the DOM is not very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You have `element` that references the element removed. Furthermore, [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) also returns a reference to the removed element. You can use these references to append it back to the DOM using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: Here is an example to the problem I am facing, I think it has to do with being inside the function. https://jsfiddle.net/Natronox/xskxvjhe/#&togetherjs=soRqnMd5hS